# How to retrieve data from dict in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, treeview

When I click on a treeview item it outputs

```
{'text': 1, 'image': '', 'values': [1, '3:18:00', 'pm'], 'open': 0, 'tags': ''}
```

How do I retrieve the specific values like the 1 or pm ? I used

```
    queryResultTable.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', select_item)

    def select_item(a):
        itemlibrary = queryResultTable.focus()
        print(queryResultTable.item(itemlibrary))
```

I tried .get but couldn't really get anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = {'text': 1, 'image': '', 'values': [1, '3:18:00', 'pm'], 'open': 0, 'tags': ''}
print(a['values'][0])
print(a['values'][2])
```

This should give you:

```
1
pm
```